# SQL stored procedure return value on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to fetch data from `[HospitalOwned]` column when the value of the column has either yes or no as the value.

I'm calling a stored procedure and after passing the value of a variable `@HospitalOwned='A'` then the values must be fetched.  I'm getting:

> an expression of non-boolean type specified in context where a
>   condition is expected
>   error

```
  case when @HospitalOwned='A' then(([HospitalOwned] like '%yes%')or([HospitalOwned] like '%no%'))end
```

Comment: You have a boolean expression in your `THEN` of your `CASE` expression. A `CASE` expression returns a scalar value, not a boolean result (it's not a CASE statement). If you're in your `WHERE` then valid syntax would be more `CASE WHEN X= 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END = 1`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `CASE` this way in SQL. `CASE` is an expression that returns a scalar value, so it can't be used for controling execution flow like in procedural languages.

Consider using this predicate instead:

```
WHERE (@HospitalOwned <> 'A') OR
      (@HospitalOwned = 'A' AND (([HospitalOwned] like '%yes%') or ([HospitalOwned] like '%no%')))
```

Comment: The OP doesn't have an `ELSE`, so I *beleive* you don't need the `(@HospitalOwned <> 'A') OR`. Simply the `AND`'s will replicate the logic they have.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, this is correct. I'm just taking a wild guess here on what he is actually trying to achieve.